# ¿Cómo puedo agrupar esta consulta de una columna con datos repetidos y la otra sin datos repetidos?

Tags: sql, postgresql

estoy practicando SQL y tengo que encontrar los mejores vendedores pertenecientes a una determinada rama de la empresa, por el momento tengo lo siguiente:

```
select idrama, nombre, apellido, max(valortotal)
from(
select personarama.idrama, persona.nombre, persona.apellido,sum(detalle.cantidad*precio.valor) as valortotal 
    from persona,factura,precio,detalle, personarama
   where persona.idpersona=factura.idvendedor
     and personarama.idpersona=persona.idpersona
     and factura.numfactura=detalle.numfactura
      and precio.referencia=detalle.referencia
      and factura.fecha between precio.fechaini and precio.fechafin
      group by persona.idpersona, personarama.idrama, persona.nombre, persona.apellido
      order by 4 DESC
) as vendedorRama
group by idrama, nombre, apellido;
```

y ello me arroja lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si agrupo sencillamente por idrama, entonces me da el resultado esperado pero no puedo obtener el nombre y apellido del vendedor.

¿Qué puedo hacer para obtener la consulta que estoy buscando?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: es decir la consulta que tienes asi como esta si sirve? o como?

Comment: @ShadowPaz si sirve, pero parcialmente, digamos ahí me está arrojando todos los vendedores por rama y sus respectivas ventas, pero yo necesito sacar sólo el mejor de cada rama.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas de resolverlo, una podría ser la siguiente.

En primer lugar crearemos un conjunto de ejemplo que representará la salida actual de tu consulta (la que te da el `valortotal` por persona y departamento`)

```
create table demo (
  idrama     varchar(4),
  nombre     varchar(255),
  apellido   varchar(255),
  valortotal NUMERIC(15,2)
);

insert into demo (idrama, nombre, apellido, valortotal) values('RM01', 'ANA', 'TORRES', 5100);
insert into demo (idrama, nombre, apellido, valortotal) values('RM01', 'DIANA', 'LOZADA', 4000);
insert into demo (idrama, nombre, apellido, valortotal) values('RM02', 'ELSA', 'PORABIOSO', 15000);
```

Luego, lo que buscamos es la persona que tiene el `valortotal` mayor del departamento, para esto:

```
with totales as (
  select idrama,
         nombre,
         apellido,
         valortotal
         from demo
)
select  t1.idrama,
        t1.nombre,
        t1.apellido,
        t1.valortotal
        from totales t1
        inner join (select idrama,
                           nombre,
                           apellido,
                           valortotal,  
                           rank() OVER (PARTITION BY idrama ORDER BY valortotal DESC) as rn
                           from totales
            ) t2
            on t1.idrama = t2.idrama
            and t1.nombre = t2.nombre
            and t1.apellido = t2.apellido
            and t1.valortotal = t2.valortotal
        where t2.rn = 1
```

La Salida:

```
| idrama | nombre |  apellido | valortotal |
|--------|--------|-----------|------------|
|   RM01 |    ANA |    TORRES |       5100 |
|   RM02 |   ELSA | PORABIOSO |      15000 |
```

Algunos comentarios:

- Al hacer un `with totales as ()` estamos usando un [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) una forma de reutilizar una determinada consulta, algo así como generar una tabla temporal "al vuelo". En tu caso deberías reemplazar lo que está entre paréntesis por tu consulta.
- Esta consulta hace uso de la función `rank()` que básicamente tal como la definimos te numera en la forma de un ranking por cada grupo de `idrama` y en el orden descendente de `valortotal`, el `rank()=1` será aquel que tenga el valor mayor.
- Ten en cuenta que si dos personas tienen el mismo valor en un departamento esta consulta retornará las dos
- También deberías hacer las relaciones por algún `id` de persona, usar nombres y apellidos  puede ser ambiguo cuando tienes dos personas con el mismo nombre y apellido.
- Una sugerencia nomás: usa `JOINs` explícitos, con la clausula `ON` te evitará algún que otro dolo de cabeza.

Te dejo un [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/601e9/6) y por último, tu consulta final, si aplicas esta solución podría quedar algo así:

```
with totales as 
(
   select   personarama.idrama, 
            persona.nombre, 
            persona.apellido,
            sum(detalle.cantidad*precio.valor) as valortotal,

            from persona,factura,precio,detalle, personarama
            where   persona.idpersona=factura.idvendedor
                    and personarama.idpersona=persona.idpersona
                    and factura.numfactura=detalle.numfactura
                    and precio.referencia=detalle.referencia
                    and factura.fecha between precio.fechaini and precio.fechafin
          group by persona.idpersona, personarama.idrama, persona.nombre, persona.apellido
)  )
select  t1.idrama,
        t1.nombre,
        t1.apellido,
        t1.valortotal
        from totales t1
        inner join (select idrama,
                           nombre,
                           apellido,
                           valortotal,  
                           rank() OVER (PARTITION BY idrama ORDER BY valortotal DESC) as rn
                           from totales
            ) t2
            on t1.idrama = t2.idrama
            and t1.nombre = t2.nombre
            and t1.apellido = t2.apellido
            and t1.valortotal = t2.valortotal
        where t2.rn = 1
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, funciona perfectamente y está muy detallada la solución!